# Some applications load the default page in the Default Web Site, some do not

Tags: asp.net, iis

IIS 6.1, Win 2008R2:

I have several applications in the Default Site. The Default Site itself is nothing but a web.config that redirects to the company home page. Some of the applications load fine, others seem to consume the web.config from the Default Site just redirect to the company home page.

I tried copying/pasting the code from a working application to a non-working application and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net Project you can set the page you want to set as start up page:

> Project Solution > right click the page you want((.aspx file) like
>   Login.aspx or any aspx file) > Set As Start Page.

Comment: The projects are identical in all the Applications:  "I tried copying/pasting the code from a working application to a non-working application and nothing changed. "